# How to fix content leaks out of an element despite use of "overflow:hidden"?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I added a search bar on my site that uses JavaScript to expand when an icon is clicked, and collapses when the input loses focus.

It works smoothly on Chrome 36 and Safari 5 but on Firefox 31 and IE 11, the contents inside the form leaks outside. I have added "*overflow: hidden*" and although it fixes the height of the form, it does not fix the position of the text. How do I fix this? Thanks.

Here is the site for preview: http://www.stackedoverflowexample01.tumblr.com/

CSS:

```
  form {
    width: 175px;
    height: 25px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  #submit {
    display: none;
  }

  form .icon {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 1px;
    right: 0;
  }

  form .submit {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    min-height: 1px;
    background: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
  }

  form #search {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: 25px;
    width: 0;
    padding: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    font-family: serif;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<form action="/search" class="search" method="get"">
  <input id="submit" value="{searchQuery}" type="submit">
  <label for="submit" class="submit"></label>
  <a href="javascript: void(0)" class="icon"><i class="icon-search"></i></a>
  <input type="search" name="q" id="search" placeholder="Search">
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".icon").click(function () {
    var icon = $(this),
        input = icon.parent().find("#search"),
        submit = icon.parent().find(".submit"),
        is_submit_clicked = false;

    input.animate({
        "width": "175px",
            "padding": "10px",
            "opacity": 1
    }, 300, function () {
        input.focus();
    });

    submit.mousedown(function () {
        is_submit_clicked = true;
    });

    icon.fadeOut(300);

    input.blur(function () {
        if (!input.val() && !is_submit_clicked) {
            input.animate({
                "width": "0",
                    "padding": "0",
                    "opacity": 0
            }, 200);

            icon.fadeIn(200);
        };
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have fixed the width and height and then used padding which throws the box-sizing off if you are not using `border-box`.

remove:

```
overflow: hidden (unnecessary)
```

add:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

change:

```
padding: 0 10px;
```

Comment: I managed to get it working by doing your suggestion. Although, the icon still leaks outside on Mozilla. Do you know how to fix this as well?